# Connection to sqlite database

Tags: java, sqlite

I tried to connect to sqlite database with java using eclipse. I added all the .jar file, but I always get an exception message says:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFound:org.sqlite.jdbc
```

Here is the code of the class responsible of connection with my database:

```
import java.sql.*;
import javax.swing.*;
public class DBConnector {

    Connection con= null;
    public static Connection DBconnector()
    {
        try{
            Class.forName("org.sqlite.jdbc");

            Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:EventData.sqlite");
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Connection Successful");

            return con;

        } catch(Exception e)
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
            return null ;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: `here the code` I see nothing, please edit question and embed code in your question, with proper formatting.

Comment: sorry but i added it in a picture via attachement

Comment: Sure, got this, but this is bad practice here, link will die one day and question becomes useless.

Comment: I guess you are not putting SQLite jar in classpath

Comment: Problem solved when I changed "org.sqlite.jdbc" with "org.sqlite.JBDC" , thank you all.